# DB2 - Getting latest Data Set based on NEW DATE and UPDATE DATE

Tags: date, db2, inner-join

I have one table A and want to retreive the latest data only for two specific values: code_id and article_id, depends if new_date or update_date is the latest date:

```
| id | article_id | code_id |       new_date      |       upd_date      |
| --------------- | ------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1  |     a      |     z   | 2023-05-31 12:22:55 |        (null)       |
| 2  |     a      |     z   | 2023-05-15 12:22:55 | 2023-05-17 12:22:55 |
| 3  |     a      |     y   | 2023-05-15 12:22:55 | 2023-05-17 12:22:55 |
...
| 4  |     b      |     y   | 2023-05-20 12:22:55 | 2023-05-21 12:22:55 |
| 5  |     b      |     z   | 2023-05-10 12:22:55 | 2023-05-31 12:22:55 |
| 6  |     b      |     y   | 2023-05-15 12:22:55 | 2023-07-01 12:22:55 |
| --------------- | ------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
```

So outcome would be:

```
| id | article_id | code_id |       new_date      |       upd_date      |
| --------------- | ------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1  |     a      |    z    | 2023-05-31 12:22:55 |        (null)       |
| 3  |     a      |    y    | 2023-05-15 12:22:55 | 2023-05-17 12:22:55 |
...
| 5  |     b      |    z    | 2023-05-10 12:22:55 | 2023-05-31 12:22:55 |
| 6  |     b      |    y    | 2023-05-15 12:22:55 | 2023-07-01 12:22:55 |
| --------------- | ------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
```

I've tried this statements, but here I can only select one date:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.code_id, 
  a.article_id, 
  a.new_date, 
  a.upd_date
FROM A a
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
      code_id, 
      article_id, 
      MAX (new_date) AS MAX_NEW_DATE
    FROM A 
    GROUP BY 
        code_id, 
        article_id) temp
ON a.code_id = temp.code_id 
AND a.new_date = temp.MAX_NEW_DATE

JOIN reference_code code 
ON a.code_id = code.code_id 
WHERE article_id = 'a'
```

Or an example with MAX CASE inside the INNER JOIN, but there I cannot compare both values with the outer table, since I'm getting only one value.

Comment: something similar has been asked and answered several times, try the search

Comment: Searched whole day but couldn't find any similar answer, only with one date.

Found an example when a start and end date is given, but this is not the case here.

Comment: What does this mean: "new_date or update_date is the latest date"?
Looking at the example data I assume You mean COALESCE(upd_date, new_date).
You could use a subselect with ROWNUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY article_id, code_id ORDER BY COALESCE(upd_date, new_date) DESC) and then fetch only lines with this rownumber == 1.

Comment: If upd_date null than new_date is the latest date, otherwise upd_date.

With COALESCE and ROWNUMBER it's working perfect, thanks!